# HREF to DIV value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I have this code:

```
<a href="test" class="1"> text</a>
```

and a `DIV` which is hidden

```
<div class="element" id="test"> x </div>
```

Is there a possibility to `href` to this id="test" ? I mean, I want to click "text" and open div with `id="test"`

Comment: Why does a `div` have a `value`?  What do you mean by "open div"?  If you're trying to show/hide elements, you likely want to employ some JavaScript functionality.

Comment: Yes, it's possible; but you need to take a few minutes and explain your question, and the problem you're trying to solve, more precisely.

Comment: Css classes can't begin with numbers, value is not a valid attribute for div elements, most likely you are looking after jquery (ex: show, slideDown, fadeIn)

Answer (score 1):

If you change `value` to `id` (`value` isn't a supported attribute for the `div` element,) you can show the hidden div by clicking the link:

```html
<div class="element" id="test" style="display:none;"> x </div>

<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'block';">text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create anchor links within the document, which cause the browser to scroll to the given element.

You need to use ID's for that:

```
<a href="#mydiv"> text</a>

<div id="mydiv"> x </div>
```

That is, the href of the link needs to point to the ID of the DIV element.

However, if you want the link to show the DIV, do something like this:

```
<a href="#mydiv" onclick="document.getElementByid('mydiv').style.display = 'block';">text</a>

<div id="mydiv" style="display:none;">This div is hidden by default, but will be visible once the link is clicked ....</div>
```

Comment: Done .... First when I read his question I thought he was just asking how to have the link point to the div, that's why I suggested the anchor functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function showDiv()
     {
         //Code to display the div
     }
</script>

<a href="#" class="1" onclick="showDiv('test')"> text</a>

<div class="element" value="test"> x </div>
```

Haven't tested but it should work something like this

Answer (score 0):

```
try this
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">          </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("a").click(function(){
     $("#test").slideDown();
  });         
    });
 </script>
 </head>
  <body>
 <a href="#">text</a>
<div id="test" style="display:none">x</div>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jquery

**HTML**:

```
<a href="#test" class="1" > text</a> //ENTER THE ID IN HREF
<div id="test" class="element" value="test"> x </div> // ENTER THE HREF AS DIV ID
```

Jquery:

```
$("a").click(function () {
    var id_name = this.hash.substr(1); //gets the text after # in href
    $("#" + id_name).show(); //it displays the div which has that id
});
```

**P.S**: you can use `toggle` instead of `show` if you want to `hide/show` onclick of `<a>` tag.

```js
$("a").click(function () {
    var id_name = this.hash.substr(1);
    $("#" + id_name).show();
});
```

```css
#test {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#test" class="1"> text</a>

<div id="test" class="element" value="test">x</div>
```